# Editable cell doesn't overlap neighbour cells in bootstrap table

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, x-editable, bootstrap-table

I use bootstrap 3 and have a [bootstrap-table](https://github.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table) table with editable cells and resizable columns. For resizing I use extension [bootstrap-table-resizable](http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/extensions/#table-resizable) and for cells editing [bootstrap-table-editable](http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/extensions/#table-editable), which uses [x-editable](https://github.com/vitalets/x-editable).

Editable cell (textarea with buttons) doesn't overlap neighbour cells. I tried to set `z-index` for editable component, but it didn't help.

[image]

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cdj0v86d/3/)

**html**

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover"  cellspacing="0" id="mainTable" data-click-to-select="true" data-show-toggle="true" data-show-columns="true" data-search="true" data-pagination="true">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th data-field="name" >Name</th>
        <th data-field="stargazers_count">Stars</th>
        <th data-field="forks_count" >Forks</th>
        <th data-field="description" >Description</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

**javascript**

```
$.fn.editable.defaults.mode = 'inline';

var data = [{name: 'ala', stargazers_count: 234, forks_count: 234, description: "asdasdas"},
           {name: 'ala', stargazers_count: 234, forks_count: 234, description: "asdasdas"},
           {name: 'ala', stargazers_count: 234, forks_count: 234, description: "asdasdas"}]

$('table').bootstrapTable({
    data: data,
  resizable: true
});

$('tr td').editable({
    type: 'textarea',
    showbuttons: true
});
```

Comment: I was hoping this was the issue I was having but it's not quite the same. Using your original fiddle, change the mode to popup and a strange behavior occurs. When you click on a cell to edit, the other cell to the right of the one you click, shift over and a new table cell appears. When you click the save/cancel buttons, everything shifts back okay. Any reasoning for this? http://jsfiddle.net/3L7vgcx0/207/

Comment: @HPWD it was really hard to fix some issues of bootstrap-table and x-editable plugin. It was long time ago. I recommend to create new question and check issues and pull requests for both repositories on Github. As I remember x-editable is not maintained any more and you can find many fixes and answers on Github. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the advice. As any project, this one is on a time crunch and need to watch for rabbit holes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to add `position: relative`. Now it works.

```
.editable-input,
.editable-buttons button{
  position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
[.editable-inline{
  position: relative;
  background-color: #fff;
  z-index: 1;
}]
```

[image: Before]

[image: After]